# BACnetServer with bacnet4j - invalid apdu in this state

Tags: java, timeout, apdu, bacnet

I'm trying to get a BACNet Server running using bacnet4j.

I use the default settings from bacnet4j and I'm able to see the bacnet server in the tool I'm using for client (Baceye).

If I have only a limited number of Datapoints on my local device, everything seems alright. But when having more than say 128 Datapoints I get Timeouts on the server and the client complains about invalid apdu in this state.

On the server I get errors like

```
Timeout while waiting for response for id 52
```

and

```
No waiting recipient for messages address = ...abortReason=Invalid APDU in this state
```

Has anyone experienced errors like this with bacnet4j and can anybody help?
Thanks!

Comment: Do you have documentation for what you're trying to accomplish here?

Comment: The problem is solved already. We use another library now... Thanks for asking...

Comment: Out of curiosity, what library? I'm currently facing the same problem.

Comment: we used a fork of bacnet4j.... https://github.com/empeeoh/BACnet4J